# Java input and output binary file byte size are not matching after transformation

Tags: java, binary

My input data set is 1201x1201 elements of 16 bit integers(2 bytes) in binary format. Total file size is 2884802 bytes. I read this data into Java using ByteBuffer and then wrote it out as a 2-dimensional array of unsigned shorts using ObjectOutputStream's writeShort() method. Now my file size is 2898893 bytes. Why this difference ?

```
    FileChannel fileInputChannel = new FileInputStream(fileInput).getChannel();
    ObjectOutputStream oos  = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileOutput));
    short[][] data = new short[1201][1201];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2884802);
    while (bb.remaining() > 0) 
        fileInputChannel.read(bb);
    fileInputChannel.close();
    bb.flip();
    ShortBuffer sb=null;
    if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)) 
        {
        sb = bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
        } 
    else 
        {
        sb = bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
        }
    for (int i=0;i<1201;i++)
        {
        for (int j=0;j<1201;j++)
            {

            data[i][j] = sb.get();
            oos.writeShort(data[i][j] & 0xFFFF);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you close the output stream.

Comment: I did not include that in the posted code but yes the output stream is closed using flush() and close() in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `DataOutputStream`, that is meant tobte used in serialization. Use the `FileOutputStream` you already have, something like this:

```
    FileChannel fileInputChannel = new FileInputStream(fileInput).getChannel();
    FileOutputStream fos  = new FileOutputStream(fileOutput);
    short[][] data = new short[1201][1201];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2884802);
    while (bb.remaining() > 0)
        fileInputChannel.read(bb);
    fileInputChannel.close();
    bb.flip();
    ShortBuffer sb=null;
    if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN))
        {
        for (int i=0;i<1201;i++)
            {
            for (int j=0;j<1201;j++)
                {
                fos.write((data[i][j] >> 8) & 0xFF);
                fos.write(data[i][j] & 0xFF);
                }
            }
        }
    else
        {
        for (int i=0;i<1201;i++)
            {
            for (int j=0;j<1201;j++)
                {
                fos.write(data[i][j] & 0xFF);
                fos.write((data[i][j] >> 8) & 0xFF);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataOutputStream, not an ObjectOutputStream. Or a ByteBuffer too. An ObjectOutputStream needs to store its classes too, to recreate objects.

In fact the above code does a simple `Files.copy`, but I assume you intend to do some processing.
Apart from the ByteOrder.